# Try catch not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, try-catch

I am trying to insert a new member into database,
when there is a duplicate the `catch` block works ok.
But when there is a new member both `try` and `catch` blocks
return their messages. here is my code.

```
if (Request["cmd"] == "ins")
{
    try{
        mydb db = new mydb();
        member newm = new member()
        {
            Id = Request["uid"],
            Name = Request["uname"]
        };

        db.AddTomembers(newm);
        db.SaveChanges();
        Response.Write("ok");
        Response.End();
    }
    catch(Exception s) {
        Response.Write(s);
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "return their messages"? Note that your code would be *much* simpler to follow if you'd fix the indentation.

Comment: On what line does the exception occur?

Comment: it's not possible that both the complete try AND the catch is triggered....

Comment: what does the response look like when it's done?

Comment: `Response.End` may be throwing your exception

Comment: maybe it's `Response.End` that's throwing the exception, but if that's the case, you should be able to figure that out from the stack trace

Comment: @Bartdude unless this chunk of code is called twice?

Comment: Learn to read exceptions. It's clear you're getting a different exception.

Comment: @Bartdude: Why not? Suppose the compiler generates a nop after the Response.End and a thread abort exception happens from another thread on that nop. In that case all the code would run in the try block and the catch block would also run. It's *possible*, it's just extremely unlikely.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: wow you're flying way too high for me :-) If you say it's possible because of that, my bad then, it's possible :-)

Comment: @Bartdude: Remember what Sherlock Holmes said about eliminating the impossible! :-)  It turns out that all kinds of ridiculously improbable things are actually possible. For instance: is it possible that `xor eax, eax` instruction -- not IL, the actual machine instruction for putting zero in eax -- generates a fault? Not a thread abort exception, an actual you-dereferenced-null kind of fault. Microsoft gets lots of crash reports and a vanishingly small but non-zero percentage of them indicate that this triggered the fault. How is that possible?  See if you can figure it out.

Comment: The solution is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/12/407562.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not really clear from the question, but I *strongly* suspect that the problem is that [`Response.End()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx) throws an exception (`ThreadAbortException`) as documented:

> To mimic the behavior of the End method in ASP, this method tries to raise a [ThreadAbortException] exception. If this attempt is successful, the calling thread will be aborted, which is detrimental to your site's performance. In that case, no code after the call to the End method is executed.

You're capturing that exception and then calling it again. Just move the `Response.End` to a `finally` block - or ideally, get rid of it entirely, structuring your control flow so you don't need it... again, as documented:

> This method is provided only for compatibility with ASP—that is, for compatibility with COM-based Web-programming technology that preceded ASP.NET. If you want to jump ahead to the EndRequest event and send a response to the client, it is usually preferable to call CompleteRequest instead.

(Note that if you'd caught a *specific* exception rather than just `Exception`, you wouldn't have this problem either.)

Comment: @Andomar: No, you can catch it - but it will be automatically rethrown at the end of the `catch` block unless you explicitly suppress that behaviour.

Comment: well the exception occur when i am trying to insert a duplicate into database and it works properly. but if i remove Response.End() , i will be sending the rest of the html to client. i just want to send a simple message to say it was successful or not .

Comment: @NarekMinaskan: What "rest of the HTML"? You haven't given us enough context here. Why would you need to send extra HTML at all? It sounds like you should probably reconsider your design for this.

Comment: No i mean , if i dont use the response.end() , its going to send the html of my page , it is visible when i alert the data from server

Comment: @NarekMinaskan: My point is that it would be better if you could take a more MVC-like approach where the response you generate is governed by the earlier results. Anyway, just moving `Response.End()` to *after* the catch block (and only having one call to it) should be a hacky way round for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If both `ok` and the exception message `s` are written, it's the Response.End() that is throwing the exception. Examine s to find out what is going on.

A guess: [Is Response.End() considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to call the `Response.End()` on the `Page_Load` event of the asp.net, it will not work properly. Take a look at this thread: [Response.End () doesn't abort current thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068184/response-end-doesnt-abort-current-thread), and see how to solve it.

Try to avoid Responses on asp.net application, try to show panels, use labels to show messages.