# What happens with ASP.Net thread after Response.End ThreadAbortException?

Tags: asp.net, threadpool, threadabortexception

There are a few  answers explaining [Is Response.End() considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful) 
However I haven't find a clear confirmation,
what would happen with ASP.Net thread after Response.End ThreadAbortException.

Eric Lippert  in his comment to
[Response.End () doesn't abort current thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068184/response-end-doesnt-abort-current-thread)
 noted  that "thread is just going to go back in the thread pool.", but he admitted, that he had  not worked on the threading model for more than 10 years.

In CodeProject article [Exploration of approaches to handle ThreadAbortException with Response.Redirect](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/164538/Back-to-the-basics-Exploration-of-approaches-to-ha)
it was told that 
"the current thread (which is taking care of the current Request) should be terminated (and go back to the Thread Pool),", 
but later it was  mentioned that
the ASP.NET worker process could face thread starvation.

Can someone  provide any references to clarify  will the thread

- be returned to the pool, or
- terminated and removed from the pool?

There is similar (not Asp.net specific) unanswered question [Aborting a thread-pool thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564891/aborting-a-thread-pool-thread?rq=1)

BTW, there is a popular beleive that ThreadAbortException can be caught by application code, but is re-thrown at the end of the catch block(sourced from [MSDN 
Thread.Abort Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx) ). However it is not correct (at least it is not always correct).
I found the code in our application, that after Response.End caught and "eat"
ThreadAbortException, and  processing is continued without any re-throw.

.